# How to translate SOAP message to webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult of SPRING WS

Tags: java, soap, ws-security, spring-ws, wss4j

I have a SOAP message call that is working on my soapUI

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:cen="http://netadmin.ghl.com/centralizedconfig" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
             <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-21">
                <wsse:Username>admin</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">secret</wsse:Password>
                <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">xo6ADfFZ5aqvukQZjUb6IQ==</wsse:Nonce>
                <wsu:Created>2013-10-01T06:59:20.202Z</wsu:Created>
             </wsse:UsernameToken>
             <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-20">
                <wsu:Created>2013-10-01T06:58:47.521Z</wsu:Created>
                <wsu:Expires>2013-10-01T07:10:47.521Z</wsu:Expires>
             </wsu:Timestamp>
          </wsse:Security>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <cen:GetXMLRequest>
             <cen:IpAddress>10.36.28.211</cen:IpAddress>
          </cen:GetXMLRequest>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

whenever I run this on my SOAP UI to test my web service, its perfectly working just fine,
I am having a difficulty translating this soap message with my **webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult** call, I am new to web service 
and I dont know how would I get to incorporate the header messages  on my code. 
can someone help me with this?

client call:

webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult
     (url,source, result);

i cant seem to include the security headers on the **source** parameter

Comment: Did you configure an interceptor in your spring configuration file ?

Comment: thanks man, i really had figured it out by configuring my client with spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added an interceptor on my spring clients application context

```
    <bean id="wss4jSecurityInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
       <property name="securementActions" value="UsernameToken" />
       <property name="securementUsername" value="user" />
       <property name="securementPassword" value="password" />
       <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="callbackHandler" />
    </bean>
```

Comment: I don't understand this solution... you're using a security interceptor on the client side? How does this modify your client soap header to create the wsse:Security head parameter you mentioned